# Adding large amount of Google contacts

Tags: android, automation, google-contacts-api

For testing purpose on Android platform I need a Google account that holds over a thousand contacts (with dummy phone numbers).  What is the best/fastest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create test Google account.
2. Create dummy names with numbers in a CSV file.
3. Import Contacts CSV file into Google account.

See: 
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14024?hl=en

Comment: Thanks.  Though I ran into some frustrations dealing with column names (namely, 'Phone' field) not being recognized during import.  Apparently the cvs column names must follow Outlook standard, or things (like phone numbers) will be dumped into Notes fields after import.

Comment: @JasonSilvery If you create a contact with a bunch of details manually in the Google account, then export it, Google will allow you to choose from a few different formats. I think one is Outlook csv but there's another, maybe it was called Google CSV. Anyway, this way you will know what all of the fields are. I just recently had to do a contact export/import myself and feel your frustrations.